# Rewriting the linear differential equations $xy\times y' - y = 1$to the form $y'(x) + p(x)y(x) = q(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation $xy\times y' - y = 1$ should be written in the form $y'(x) + p(x)y(x) = q(x)$

Dividing by $xy$ leaves me with $q(x) = \frac{1}{xy}$ and I dont know how to work with this when solving the equation with $y = e^{-\int Pdx} \times (\int q(x)e^{\int Pdx} + C_{0})$

Any leads?

Comment: You cant really do it since it's not linear. It is however separable so you can use methods associated with separable differential equations instead if the aim is to solve it.

Comment: @Squid You can, if you consider the equation $\frac{dx}{dy} = \dots$ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$xy\frac{dy}{dx}-y=1$$
As already pointed out, the ODE is separable and can be straightforward solved.

But if you definitively want to transform it to a linear ODE, change of symbols :
$$\begin{cases}
x=Y\\
y=X
\end{cases}
\quad\to\quad YX\frac{dX}{dY}-X=1\quad\to\quad \frac{dX}{dY}=\frac{X+1}{XY}$$

$$\frac{dY}{dX}-\frac{X}{X+1}Y=0$$
$$\frac{dY}{dX}+pY=q\qquad \begin{cases}p=-\frac{X}{X+1}\\q=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Basically you just could say that instead of solving equation for $y(x)$ we can write equation for $x(y)$ and for it the equation becomes linear :)

Comment: @Evgeny : Of couse. But some people not familiar with inverse function would appreciate a clearer picture.

Answer (score 0):

we have by dividing by $$xy\ne 0$$ $$y'-\frac{1}{xy}=\frac{1}{x}$$